# Input box not calling function

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me why my onchange or onkeypress doesn't work? It seems to not be calling the function at all.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
X:<input type="number" id="boxwidth" onChange="myfunction()"/>
Y:<input type="number" id="boxheight" onkeypress="draw()"/>
```

Script:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
context.stroke();

function myfunction(){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The JShint says the javascript code is valid. Would i see errors there?

Comment: That will only show syntax errors. What I'm interested is if there are errors in the browser console when it should be calling the functions.

Comment: The `draw` function is not defined anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: you can change it myfunction as well. Ive simplified the code to isolate this problem

Comment: Got it, its the capital C in onChange - should onchange...feel like an idiot

Comment: The C should not matter with it as an attribute....

Comment: Yeah, I tested it with `onchange` and `onChange` and both worked.